# Does the reply of PING contain the original data?

Tags: c#, ping

I am using C# Ping class to ping a server.

If I send the ping with a buffer (say 10240 bytes), will the server come back with also the original 10240 bytes?

I ask this because I am measuring the latency between two endpoints, together with the data size (to see how much impact of the data size on the latency in Ping).

If I ping with 10240 bytes, will the server send the reply back with 10240 bytes, or just tell me that it receives, not with 10240 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the icmp reply should contain all the data.

Note that when you're sending packets that big - it'll likely get fragmented at the IP layer - and that can typically be expensive. e.g. TCP will try to not send packets that gets fragmented but slice the data up in segments fitting the MTU.

Answer (score 2):

It will echo all the data.  See [ping: Message format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Message_format).

Answer (score 0):

from rfc 792

" The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo
      reply message."

can an icmp packet be 10k? I doubt it

Comment: On success, it must return the entirety of the data.  It's also allowed to fail.